How to prevent Invisible reCAPTCHA v2 badge from stealing focus?
I'm trying to implement Invisible reCAPTCHA v2 on a site, and I've noticed that as soon as the badge renders on the page, it steals focus from whatever element had it before it appeared. It also causes keyboard navigation to jump to the privacy and terms of service links in the badge if the tab key is pressed. Is there a way to prevent all of this from happening? I tried using the tabindex parameter for grecaptcha.render to set tabindex to 200, but this doesn't have any effect. Any suggestions?
What I tried:
I loaded invisible recaptcha v2 on a login page where the password field is focused by default.
What I expected:
I expected to be taken to the password field when I arrive on this page, and to be able to tab to the login button via the keyboard.
What actually happened:
What actually happened is that the focus was removed from the password field, and when I tried to tab, I was taken to the privacy link in the recaptcha badge.
